# Giving an Error when adding firebase library and AHT10 library together

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp32

I wrote a code to get the temperature and send the data to the firebase DB using ESP32

but there is an error when adding the `AHTX0 library` to the code.
This is the error.
what is the error?
thanks in advance

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core 1 register dump:
PC : 0x400e7fcf PS : 0x00060f30 A0 : 0x800e7f16 A1 : 0x3ffb2720
A2 : 0x00000000 A3 : 0x3ffb2747 A4 : 0x00000003 A5 : 0x00000001
A6 : 0x00000000 A7 : 0x00000000 A8 : 0x800e85be A9 : 0x3ffb2700
A10 : 0x0000472d A11 : 0x00000000 A12 : 0x0000472d A13 : 0x00006d80
A14 : 0x00003934 A15 : 0x00393430 SAR : 0x0000000a EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0x0000000c LBEG : 0x40084765 LEND : 0x4008476d LCOUNT : 0x00000027

Backtrace:0x400e7fcc:0x3ffb27200x400e7f13:0x3ffb2740 0x400d36f3:0x3ffb2770 0x400ea895:0x3ffb2820
```

This is the code.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Firebase_ESP_Client.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_AHTX0.h>

#include "time.h"

// Provide the token generation process info.
#include "addons/TokenHelper.h"
// Provide the RTDB payload printing info and other helper functions.
#include "addons/RTDBHelper.h"

// Insert your network credentials
#define WIFI_SSID "slt fibre"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "wifi-password"

// Insert Firebase project API Key
#define API_KEY "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

// Insert Authorized Email and Corresponding Password
#define USER_EMAIL "xxxxxxx@gmail.com"
#define USER_PASSWORD "xxxxxxx"

// Insert RTDB URLefine the RTDB URL
#define DATABASE_URL "https://esp32-weather-app-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app"

// Define Firebase objects
FirebaseData fbdo;
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseConfig config;

// Variable to save USER UID
String uid;

// Database main path (to be updated in setup with the user UID)
String databasePath;
// Database child nodes
String tempPath = "/temperature";
String humPath = "/humidity";
String presPath = "/pressure";
String timePath = "/timestamp";

// Parent Node (to be updated in every loop)
String parentPath;

int timestamp;
FirebaseJson json;

const char* ntpServer = "pool.ntp.org";

// BME280 sensor
// I2C
float temperature;
float humidity;
float pressure;

// Timer variables (send new readings every three minutes)
unsigned long sendDataPrevMillis = 0;
unsigned long timerDelay = 180000;

// Initialize BME280


// Initialize WiFi
void initWiFi() {
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi ..");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print('.');
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();
}

// Function that gets current epoch time
unsigned long getTime() {
  time_t now;
  struct tm timeinfo;
  if (!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)) {
    //Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
    return (0);
  }
  time(&now);
  return now;
}
Adafruit_AHTX0 aht;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Initialize BME280 sensor

  initWiFi();
  configTime(0, 0, ntpServer);

  // Assign the api key (required)
  config.api_key = API_KEY;

  // Assign the user sign in credentials
  auth.user.email = USER_EMAIL;
  auth.user.password = USER_PASSWORD;

  // Assign the RTDB URL (required)
  config.database_url = DATABASE_URL;

  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
  fbdo.setResponseSize(4096);

  // Assign the callback function for the long running token generation task */
  config.token_status_callback = tokenStatusCallback; //see addons/TokenHelper.h

  // Assign the maximum retry of token generation
  config.max_token_generation_retry = 5;

  // Initialize the library with the Firebase authen and config
  Firebase.begin(&config, &auth);

  // Getting the user UID might take a few seconds
  Serial.println("Getting User UID");
  while ((auth.token.uid) == "") {
    Serial.print('.');
    delay(1000);
  }

  // Print user UID
  uid = auth.token.uid.c_str();
  Serial.print("User UID: ");
  Serial.println(uid);

  // Update database path
  databasePath = "/UsersData/" + uid + "/readings";

}

void loop() {

  // Send new readings to database
  if (Firebase.ready() && (millis() - sendDataPrevMillis > timerDelay || sendDataPrevMillis == 0)) {
    sendDataPrevMillis = millis();

    //Get current timestamp
    timestamp = getTime();
    Serial.print ("time: ");
    Serial.println (timestamp);

    parentPath = databasePath + "/" + String(timestamp);
    sensors_event_t humidity, temp;
    aht.getEvent(&humidity, &temp);

    json.set(tempPath.c_str(), temp.temperature);
    json.set(humPath.c_str(), humidity.relative_humidity);
    json.set(presPath.c_str(), String(22 / 100.0F));
    json.set(timePath, String(timestamp));
    Serial.printf("Set json... %s\n", Firebase.RTDB.setJSON(&fbdo, parentPath.c_str(), &json) ? "ok" : fbdo.errorReason().c_str());
  }
}
```

I've looked for problems in Firebase.h and FirebaseArduino.h and I haven't see any problem

Comment: Download [ESPExceptionDecoder](https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder) plugin, run the trace and if you can't identify the source of the cause, update your post by adding the trace.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't call the `begin()` method on the `aht` object. The `begin()` method initializes it and prepares it for use. If you don't call it before using other methods in the library the results will be undefined and can likely cause a crash like you're seeing.

Your code:

```
Adafruit_AHTX0 aht;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Initialize BME280 sensor

  initWiFi();
```

Should look like this:

```
Adafruit_AHTX0 aht;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if(!aht.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Could not find AHT? Check wiring");
    while(1)
      delay(10);
  }

  Serial.println("AHT10 or AHT20 found");

  initWiFi();
```

Adafruit puts a lot of energy into writing [examples](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_AHTX0/tree/master/examples) and [tutorials](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-aht20) for their products and software. If you're having a problem with one of them those are a good place to start.